# Spontaneous file open bug at second time

Tags: c++, file

When trying to read a file in a second time, the fopens function just crash my program returning no errors. And the weird thing is that the same function was working moments ago, and then is crashing at the same point after debugging

> (The location of the files has not been changed)

> (When i change the order of the files been readed is still the same, can read the first time, but the second time just crash)

```
vector<triangle> loadObj(const char* sfileName){
        FILE* f = new FILE;
        f = fopen(sfileName,"r");

        if(f==nullptr){
            fclose(f);
            return {};
        }
        //Cache
        vector<vec3d> ve;
        vec3d v;
        vector<triangle> cache;
        char line[100];

       while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
            strstream s;
            s  << line;
            char junk;
            if(line[0]=='v'){
                s >> junk >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
               ve.push_back(v);
            }
            else if(line[0]=='f'){
                int p1,p2,p3;
                s >> junk >> p1 >> p2 >> p3;
                triangle t;
                t.vertexs[0] = ve[p1-1];
                t.vertexs[1] = ve[p2-1];
                t.vertexs[2] = ve[p3-1];
                cache.push_back(t);
            }
        }
    fclose(f);
    return cache;
}
```

Use function:

```
mesh* loadMesh(const char* file){
    mesh* cubo = (mesh*) malloc(sizeof(mesh));
    if (cubo == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    cubo->tris = {};
    cubo->tris = loadObj(file);
    return cubo;
}
```

Comment: is there any reason you use C io in C++ ?

Comment: `mesh* cubo = (mesh*) malloc(sizeof(mesh));`  looks also wrong. Depending on what `mesh` is this can summon nasal demons or worse

Comment: `FILE* f = new FILE;` followed by `f = fopen(...)` leads to a memory leak.

Comment: the mesh if fine i guess, when i printf after the fopen() dont pops up anything so i guess this is my nasal demon. My mesh is just this
typedef struct mesh{
    vector<triangle> tris;
}mesh;

Comment: Please read about [mcve].

Comment: there is no `mesh` in the code you show us. The code allocates some memory that can potentially hold a `mesh`, but there is no `mesh`. "looks fine" is a possible outcome of undedined behavior (imho the worst)

Comment: If your crash is that repeatable, have you used your debugger?

Comment: struct mesh{ vector<triangle> tris; } is certainly something that you should not allocate with malloc.

Comment: As for finding and fixing crashes, please use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to figure where in your code it happens, and to examine involved variables and their values.

Comment: it was really just the FILE*p = new FILE....

Comment: oh, now I understand a bit more of the code. This `cubo->tris = loadObj(file);`  is certainly undefined. You are calling the assignment operator of a `std:.vector` but there is no `std::vector`. `malloc` cannot possibly construct a `std::vector`. Franky, your code is wrong due to mixing C with C++ without understanding what the C part actually does

Comment: you need to find some ressources that show you how to write actual C++. There is a lot of crap out there. If you see C++ material that tells you about `malloc` and `fopen` then you either landed in the super advanced chapters that you do not need to read now or the material is simply crap.

Comment: well actually is just what i learned in college, i'm using malloc even thought i dont need it....right?

Comment: `malloc` should almost never be used in C++ code. If you need dynamic allocation, `make_unique` or `make_shared` (or `new` if you really need to).

Comment: there is no reason to dynamically allocate `mesh` in the first place. The function should be `mesh loadMesh(const std::string& file)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mesh` class is clearly defined as something like:

```
struct mesh{
   vector<triangle> tris;
}
```

Aside from C-style structs with no C++ features in use (structs essentially 100% compatible with C), `malloc` is inappropriate for safely allocating classes in C++; it won't actually *construct* `tris`, it'll just leave whatever random bytes were left in the heap *as if* they were *already* a validly constructed `vector<triangle>`, and the odds of that being correct are near zero.

Attempting to assign to `cubo->tris` with `cubo->tris = {};` then tries to free the existing contents of said `vector`, which does terrible, random, and undefined things. `placement new` *could* be used to make this work. But don't do that, because now you need to manually destruct the contents, and you're not deriving any benefit either way. Using C allocators for C++-classes is a *bad* idea, don't do it.

Short answer: If you're using C++ features, use C++ allocators like `new`/`delete` (or better, `std::make_unique`/`std::make_shared`), not `malloc`/`free`. In this case, there's no reason I can determine for dynamic allocation, so it's possible the correct solution is to just return by value instead:

```
mesh loadMesh(const char* file){
    return {loadObj(file)};  // Or return mesh(loadObj(file)); or whatever makes
                             // sense for the actual definition of mesh
}
```

Comment: The part of the file bug was just the "new FILE" that i put after, but now i correct the struct of my data using new instead of malloc :) Thanks

Comment: @DaltonGomes: Ah, yes, `new FILE` is flat wrong, but it's just a memory *leak*, not memory *corruption*; the `fopen` on the next line replaces it with something valid before you manage to do anything truly terrible. `FILE *f = fopen(sfileName,"r");` is what you want. (Side-note: I *always* put the `*` next to the variable name, not the type, because that's how C/C++ sees it; `FILE* f1, f2;` would actually declare `f1` as a `FILE*`, and `f2` as a `FILE` *value*; putting the `*` with the variable `FILE *f1, f2;` makes that mistake more obvious, when you want `FILE *f1, *f2;`)